# Fast AI Api doc for leaner.fine_tune

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I was looking for FastAI API Docs.

I could see code as ,

```
dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_name_func('.',
    get_image_files(path), valid_pct=0.2, seed=42,
    label_func=is_cat,
    item_tfms=Resize(192)) # Data Loader

learner = vision_learner(dls, resnet18, metrics=error_rate)
learner.fine_tune(3)
```

I could see some [API_DOC](https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#learner)  and [Source](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/fastai/learner.py#L98) ,but I am not able to find, learner.fine_tune() API and what arguments it takes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the arguments here
https://docs.fast.ai/callback.schedule.html#learner.fine_tune